# tensorflow-js: How to display a graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I have debugging some `tfjs` code describing a graph with simple operations but mixing placeholder and trainables. It would be very useful to have a graph visualization of my model, such as provided by https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graph_viz .

Is there such as thing within the javascript API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tfjs-vis has a method that renders an HTML table summary of the model's topology:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-vis#showmodelsummarycontainer-drawable-model-tfmodel--promise

But TF.js currently provides no graphical rendering of model topology.

There are a few workarounds,

1. You can save the TF.js model, convert it to a Keras model using [tfjs converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter#getting-started) and use Keras' [plot_model](https://keras.io/visualization/) method to generate a png image of the model's topology
2. Use TensorSpace (a third-party tool): https://tensorspace.org/

Comment: Many thanks for the input, the canonical solution and the workarounds!